# Load a file with javascript externally using php

Tags: javascript, php, curl, external, file-get-contents

I have one file named ad.php. In this file i load some ads from external pages.

`(ad.php)`:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='www.example.org'></script>...`

And one file named: `(index.php)`.

I want to load the contents of the file ad.php finished and then spend it in the index.php file.

I don't want, that the user loads the javascript files.

i tried some ways:

- file_get_contents
- curl

But the javascript files were loaded in the index.php by the user.
Is it possible to load the ad.php externally using php?

Comment: You have JavaScript in a PHP file?

Comment: Use AJAX, or frames...

Comment: Did you mean Iframes?

Comment: If ads are delivered via JS, how can you avoid loading JS on your index page?

Comment: Ad networks rely on client-side code.  It allows them to get more information about users, enables more ad functionality, and allows you to prevent loading ads until your core content has rendered.  There are some ad networks that allow inserting ads into e-mails.  Those would be compatible with your method.  Are you making your own ad server, or using an existing network?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your php.ini and set

```
allow_url_include = 1      
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

you can use include("http://example.com/ad.php")
this would be the best way if you don't want to use JS.
If you want to use JS you could use XMLHttpRequests